# strcpy() And strcat() are not working properly in Turbo C++ (when initializing array from string litteral)

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

The strcpy() and strcat() functions are not working properly for
me in Turbo C++. I have given my code below. I want the output to
be:

```
C:\TURBOC3\BIN\BANK\SHOP\SELLER\334pd.txt
C:\TURBOC3\BIN\BANK\SHOP\SELLER\334pr.txt
C:\TURBOC3\BIN\BANK\SHOP\CART\311itm.txt

C:\TURBOC3\BIN\BANK\SHOP\CART\311pzr.txt
```

But The Output I Am Getting Is :

```
C:\TURBOC3\BIN\BANK\SHOP\SELLER\334pd.txt
C:\TURBOC3\BIN\BANK\SHOP\SELLER\334pr.txt
C:\TURBOC3\BIN\BANK\SHOP\CART\311itm.txt  
4pd.txt
```

Can anyone please point out the error in my code and how to solve it?

```
void add_to_cart(int se_id,int c_id,char p_name[])
{
    char id_seller[100],id_customer[100],id_seller1[100],id_customer1[100];
    itoa(se_id,id_seller,10);
    itoa(se_id,id_seller1,10);
    itoa(c_id,id_customer,10);
    itoa(c_id,id_customer1,10);
    strcat(id_seller,"pd.txt");
    strcat(id_seller1,"pr.txt");
    strcat(id_customer,"itm.txt");
    strcat(id_customer1,"pzr.txt");
    char location_of_cart_product[]="C:\\TURBOC3\\BIN\\BANK\\SHOP\\CART\\",location_of_cart_price[100];
    char location_of_product[]="C:\\TURBOC3\\BIN\\BANK\\SHOP\\SELLER\\",lop[100];
    strcpy(location_of_cart_price,location_of_cart_product);
    strcpy(lop,location_of_product);
    strcat(location_of_cart_product,id_customer);
    strcat(location_of_cart_price,id_customer1);
    strcat(lop,id_seller1);
    strcat(location_of_product,id_seller);
    puts(location_of_product);
    puts(lop);
    puts(location_of_cart_product);
    puts(location_of_cart_price);
}
```

Comment: ***Can Anyone Please Tell The Error In My Code*** even turbo c++ has a debugger that lets you step through your code a line at a time looking at variables at each step. I remember I used it thousands of hours in the 1990s.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code line by line in the built-in debugger? And how do you call this function you show? With what arguments? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Please avoid capitalizing the whole post as though it's a title. That is incredibly distracting.

Comment: See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your duplicates accounts.

Answer (score 4):

These statements:

```
char location_of_cart_product[]="C:\\TURBOC3\\BIN\\BANK\\SHOP\\CART\\"
char location_of_product[100]="C:\\TURBOC3\\BIN\\BANK\\SHOP\\SELLER\\"
```

Allocate an array of size 33. You cannot append to this array using strcat without smashing your stack. See [array initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization)

You can write:

```
char location_of_cart_product[100]="C:\\TURBOC3\\BIN\\BANK\\SHOP\\CART\\";
char location_of_product[100]="C:\\TURBOC3\\BIN\\BANK\\SHOP\\SELLER\\";
```

Which will allocate 100 characters and initialize the first part of the array with the string.

Comment: Thank You So Much Sir. It Worked.Thanks A Lot